# como puedo resolver el scroll animado en wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, scroll

estoy tratando de seguir un tutorial en donde animan los elementos con el scroll cuando lo uso en un archivo html normal si funciona pero cuando aplico el  mismo codigo de javascript en wordpress no funciona como se puede resolver esto?

```
const target = document.querySelectorAll('[data-anime]');
const animationClass = 'animate';

function animeScroll() {
  const windowTop = window.pageYOffset;
  target.forEach(function(element) {
    if((windowTop) > element.offsetTop) {
        element.classList.add(animationClass);
      }
      console.log(element.offsetTop);
  })
}

  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    animeScroll();
  })
```

el codigo css

```css
.cont_all{
    display: flex;
}

.a{
    background: red;
    margin: 15px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}

[data-anime] {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .3s;
  }

  [data-anime="left"] {
    transform: translate3d(-50px, 0, 0);
  }

  [data-anime="right"] {
    transform: translate3d(50px, 0, 0);
  }

  [data-anime="top"] {
    transform: translate3d(0, -50px, 0);
  }

  [data-anime].animate {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  }
```

y en el worpress solo agrego el selector data-anime="left" dependiendo de donde quiero que salga la animacion

Comment: está el javascript al final del código? se carga el contenido por ajax? tal vez tengas que englobar el script en un `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {   /* código */ });` para que encuentre los attr ( fijate si en el código fuente de la página no te está removiendo o escapeando esos attrs )